# How to disable automatic updates on Kubuntu 20.04?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 20.04, automatic, adblock

I would like to disable automatic updates in kubuntu 20.04. I disabled it on Muon package manager, but Discover still getting updates and showing notifications.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**WARNING**: Disabling Unattended Upgrades is NOT recommended for most users. Doing so may leave your system vulnerable.

**Prerequisite**: You need to know how to use a text editor and proper use of sudo before starting. If you are unfamiliar with those, then you *really* should not be trying to stop Unattended Upgrades yet.

This method won't damage your system.

Open a terminal and carefully edit the following config file: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

It looks like this:

```
    APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
    APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Change both "1" to "0". Save and close.

In order to restore Unattended Upgrades, change both "0" back to "1".

Comment: Hello. When I opened the file 20auto-upgrades all values already had "0". APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0"; , but discover getting updates.

Comment: I would think to disable automatic downloads should be more simple. Like ticking the box in settings menu or turning off a service. Why it is not like that in Kubuntu, ubuntu and other unix OSes?

Comment: This directory /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades controls Muon package manager. Discover most probably have another?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Boomer, I don't know why is so difficult to find this option in Kubuntu, when is so easy in others distros.

I was looking for that like crazy and after a while that's the first help that really worked, for some reason it's quite normal to Kubuntu have some issues when update, so I needed to disable to stop lost drivers and have kernel issues.

Just to complete the correct answer, after that check if you did it right:

```
apt-config dump APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade
apt-config dump APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists
```

Should return 0 for both commands.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: The following answer can potentially damage your system**

In Ubuntu 20.04, "Software Updates" is a python script located at `/usr/bin/update-manager`.

Just put an exit command at line 2 and wherever it's launched it will do nothing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
exit()
```

Comment: It will stop all kinds of updates

Comment: Not "all kinds of updates", as "apt" from command line will work without problems, nevertheless I put the initial disclaimer.