# How do I disable updates in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: updates

The notorious updates keep showing up in Ubuntu 20.04. Is there any way to disable them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable automatic updates on Kubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235306/how-to-disable-automatic-updates-on-kubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Updates are not notorious, nor onerous. They are part of normal maintenance. Must updates are either security patches or critical bugfixes.

Comment: Since 17.10 I have found it impossible to disable update notifications: you are given the option to remove them, but it doesn't do anything.

Snap updates are forced through and this cannot be changed. Canonical are explicit about this.

Comment: You can uninstall `unattended-upgrades` and disable "automatically check for updates", **but this does not mean that you should try to avoid updates**.  Updates are a critical part of regular maintenance, especially for internet connected devices. If you disable automatic updates, you should set aside time to do them manually at least once per month.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want updates?

Comment: Yes... install them.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I have the same problem currently

Answer (score 1):

Although update is good, but if you want to disable it you can do so with these simple steps.

1. Open the software & updates application
2. Select “Updates” tab.
3. from “Automatically check for updates” option, select Never.

and your update will be disabled, until you want that back.
thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should add that "Software and updates" can be run manually any time.

Comment: I did that, but it still pops up annoying messages every now and then, saying that updates are available. I can't seem to be able to get rid of them.

Comment: I confirm, on 20.04 LTS, even disabling this "automatic check for update" it's still showing available updates from time to time: this is unacceptable when you are running billed internet connection (bill can add up quickly).

Comment: Can confirm as well, that disabling the mentioned setting does not solve the issue. In my case: I have apt repositories that are only available when using a VPN. Ubuntu keeps showing an error message each time I login.